# Excel: Using VBA to Search a Cell, for a Range of values, and return a Hit

Tags: vba, excel, search

So I have 10,000+ Rows of Horrible-unformatted-semi-legible-mumbo-jumbo. I have posted my formulas below. I will run out of space in the formula line shortly, and it's not a very efficient method.

The data looks like this:

```
SCHMIDT,|JOHN|JACOB|JINGLE-HEIMER|PO|BOX|98765|1234|OCTAVIAN|ST|N|100|MILE|HOUSE|
JIMBOB,|JOEY|JAN|PO|BOX|-|98765|1234|MERCER|RD|E|VANCOUVER|
HEISENBERG,|RR|1|-|98765|1234|FRANKLIN|AVE|S|NORTH|VANCOUVER|
MAN,|HE|98765|1234|SKELETOR|PL|W|100|POCO|
RINGO,|JULIUS|CHARLES|98765|1234|SKELETOR|CRES|NE|100|POCO|
BAJINGO,|DOCTOR|SCRUBS|98765|1234|HOSPITAL|RD|NW|100|EAST|VANCOUVER|
```

What you see does not exactly always appear in the order that it is in; for example "PO BOX" is absent/present, or at the beginning or the middle or the end of the line. Not all Address_Lines have a Suite number, and not all Suite-Address_Line have a "-" separating the two.

At this point, I want to extract the Direction (N,E,S,W,NE,NW,SE,SW) if any, and the Address_line Suffix (Rd, St, Cres, etc.).

These are my formulas:

Line Suffix `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("|ST|",A2)),"ST",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("|RD|",A2)),"RD",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("|AVE|",A2)),"AVE",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("|PL|",A2)),"PL"))))`

Direction `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("|N|",A2)),"N",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("|E|",A2)),"E",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("|S|",A2)),"S",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("|W|",A2)),"W"))))`

Can I please get some help rewriting these formulas as two separate functions, in VBA?

My thinking is that I call Search() using a CASE function for the Search_Text on a given cell? I just have no idea to go about this.

I would like to be able to call this function on demand by typing it in a cell on the spreadsheet, by referring to the raw string.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function FOne(v As Variant) As String
Dim vSearch As Variant, c As Variant

vSearch = Array("|ST|", "|RD|", "|AVE|", "|PL|")

For Each c In vSearch
    If InStr(1, v, c) Then
        FOne = Mid(c, 2, Len(c) - 2)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next c

End Function
```

and

```
Function FTwo(v As Variant) As String
Dim vSearch As Variant, c As Variant

vSearch = Array("|N|", "|E|", "|S|", "|W|")

For Each c In vSearch
    If InStr(1, v, c) Then
        FTwo = Mid(c, 2, Len(c) - 2)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next c

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes the most sense to me with my limited experience with object oriented  languages.

Answer (score 1):

Try This code as your base, and take from there.

Main sub takes the string in cell(1,1) and extract the direction and address line to cells(1,2) and (1,3) using  `searchForText` function.

You should be able to modify it to fit according to your needs, if not let me know.

```
Sub Main()
Dim values As Variant
values = Array("|N|", "|E|", "|W|", "|S|", "|NE|", "|NW|", "|SE|", "|SW|")
Cells(1, 2).Value = SearchForText(values)
values = Array("RD", "ST", "CRES") 'fill in the rest of optional values
Cells(1, 3).Value = SearchForText(values)
End Sub

Function SearchForText(values As Variant) As String

Dim line As String
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer
line = Cells(1, 1).Value
For k = 0 To UBound(values)
For j = Len(line) To Len(values(k)) + 1 Step -1
If Mid(line, j - Len(values(k)), Len(values(k))) = values(k) Then
GoTo result
End If
Next j
Next k
result:
values(k) = Left(values(k), Len(values(k)) - 1)   'remove vertical lines
values(k) = Right(values(k), Len(values(k)) - 1)
SearchForText = values(k)
End Function
```

Comment: I am working through this answer still untill I fully grasp it. It is not wrong, as it gets the job done. I will follow-up when I fully grasp it.

Comment: What I've done here is to build a version of InStr function which reads from right to left, instead of left to right as in the original InStr function. This is because the value you are looking for is closer to the end of the string than the beginning. This will save you a few milliseconds each line. If you add it to 10,000 lines this could improve your runtime.